# how to get value of second position of '_' from the right?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data like aa_bb_cc_dddd_eeeee, here i need to get the data dddd_eeeee means backwards of the second positon of '_'  and there is not constant length between the _ , how can I get the value? thank you very much!

```
DECLARE @Parameter VARCHAR(100)
SET @Parameter='aa_bb_cc_dddd_eeeee'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT RIGHT (@Parameter, 
              CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@Parameter), -- find 2nd from right
              CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@Parameter)) + 1) - 1)  -- find 1st from right
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Any method to write it backward? if given the lengh and number of '_' from the left is not fixed. thanks again :)

Comment: Thank you!! :) have a nice day~